# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have a strange problem. I have a [JMS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/JMS) client application & an [MDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans#Message_driven_beans) configured in JBoss `jboss-5.1.0.GA`. Earlier, I added the JAR by "Configure Build Path" → "Add External JARs" and everything was working fine.

Now, I moved all the JARs to a lib folder under my project and used "Configure Build Path" → "Add JARs".

Now, I get the following exception while executing the client program :(

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.<clinit>(NamingContext.java:160)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory.getInitialContext(NamingContextFactory.java:56)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.dcat2.messaging.sendreceive.MessageReceiver_test.sendMessage(MessageReceiver_test.java:68)
at com.dcat2.messaging.sendreceive.MessageReceiver_test.main(MessageReceiver_test.java:57)
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 8 more
```

I have `jndi.properties` in the classpath and the following JARs:

```
jbossall-client.jar
commons-logging.jar
concurrent.jar
javax.ejb.jar
jms.jar
jnp-client-4.2.2.GA.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
sqljdbc4.jar
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: How are you executing the client program?

Comment: can you show the imports? It seems you are trying to use the jboss logger but you have log4j on the class path. May be you should import org.apache.log4j

Comment: @peshkira.... I have used import org.apache.log4j

Comment: @Raze2dust... I am executing from eclipse --> Run as Java Application

Answer (score 3):

You need `jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA`, which comes with the Hibernate distribution or can be downloaded separately.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they may be missing the `lib/` folder in the classpath. Did you update the classpath to point to the lib folder? If you have a manifest file, make sure it references the lib folder for the jars. Print out your classpath when your program runs, then you can see if it points to those jars. The eclipse setting is only good in eclipse, so if you go outside of that, you have to watch the classpath.

Comment: Hi All,
When I added the jbossall-client.jar from tje jboss installtion path(../jboss-5.1.0.GA\client) and not from the lib folder, it worked.So, can't I add this jar to lib folder & include in my buildpath? Any idea?

Comment: Also, i tried adding the following in manifest file and tried. But got the same problem    Class-Path: ../lib/jbossall-client.jar

Comment: That only works if the jbossall-client.jar file is in your jar. Does your jar have a lib folder in it?

Comment: Yes...
The real problem was jbossall-client.jar contains references to other jars. Hence we need to add it from the JBOSS_HOME. Thats is why it didnt work when i copied to my lib directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was that the `jbossall-client.jar` contains references to other JARs. Hence, we need to add it from the `JBOSS_HOME`. That's why it didn't work when I copied to my `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's the issue with the JBoss logger's compatibility with JDK upgrade from 1.7 on-wards. JDK 1.7 does not allow custom levels. Please use a library compatible with JDK 1.7 (Hit and Try). Maybe, `lib doc` can help in it.

Otherwise, change the problem JAR by yourself (not recommended).