# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

**JBoss Server Version : 7.3**

**Java Version : 1.8**

**IDE : eclipse**

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.<clinit>(InitialContextFactory.java:64)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.Client.main(Client.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

Below mentioned jars are added in build-path even after getting exception. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger .

```
jbossall-client.jar
jboss-common-client.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
jboss-remote-naming-1.0.7.final.jar
```

**Code**
Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InputStream input;
            input = new FileInputStream("/lookup.properties");
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(input);
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(getJBossClientProperties());
            Object obj = initialContext.lookup(prop.getProperty("lookup"));
            System.out.println("Got EJB : "+obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error : "+e);
        }
    }

    private static Properties getJBossClientProperties() throws Exception {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("/config.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(input);
        return prop;
    }
```

lookup.properties

```
lookup=jndi_lookup
```

config.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried above in glassfish works fine , i know its jboss...
I found another relevant post here

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10948948)

grep for;
When I added the jbossall-client.jar from tje jboss installtion path(../jboss-5.1.0.GA\client) and not from the lib folder, it worked.

that could be your answer.....